# R extension not formating on VScode

Tags: windows-11, visual-studio-code, r, vscode-extensions

I've installed the VScode extensio "R" `v2.5.0` by REditorSupport. After some debugging, I had it working so I could `Alt` + `Shift` + `F` and have VScode auto-indent my R code. Then I opened RStudio, did some stuff and went back to VScode only to find receive a message saying `There is no formatted for 'r' files installed.` (image below).

What gives? I didn't uninstall anything, the extension is still there and I can't find any setting that looks like `formatting` or `indent`.

## How can I configure the R extension to keep auto-indenting my R code?

[image]

Comment: Hi, did you ever find an solution? I'm experiencing the same issues after trying to setup R & Visual Studio on a new PC. I've got the extension, `styler` and `languageserver` installed, and the autocomplete and syntax highlighting are working fine, but the formatting just won't work.